Doubly transitive groups in which a point stabilizer has an abelian normal subgroup
Let $G$ be a finite doubly transitive group in its action on the set $X$, such that a point stabilizer $G_x$ ($x \in X$) has an abelian normal subgroup $N_x$.
I have read that if $\vert N_x \vert$ is even and $N_x$ acts semi-regularly on $X \setminus \{ x \}$ (Hering, 1972), or if $N_x$ does not act semi-regularly on $X \setminus \{ x \}$ (O'Nan, 1975), such permutation groups are classified without CFSG.
Has there been any progress in the meanwhile on the case where $\vert X \vert$ is even, $\vert N_x \vert$ is odd and $N_x$ acts semi-regularly on $X \setminus \{ x\}$, again without CFSG ?
What about upon assuming the additional condition that $\vert X \vert - 1$ is an odd prime power ?
